# MySQL Docker Image

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I have a very simple Docker file (below) that is using the base image `mysql:latest`; which copies in a SQL seeding script from a dump file that I've created, for e2e testing of an app.

```
FROM mysql:latest

RUN chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/

ARG MYSQL_DATABASE
ARG MYSQL_USER
ARG MYSQL_PASSWORD
ARG MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQL_DATABASE
ENV MYSQL_USER=$MYSQL_USER
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

ADD seed-data.sql /etc/mysql/seed-data.sql
RUN sed -i 's/MYSQL_DATABASE/'$MYSQL_DATABASE'/g' /etc/mysql/seed-data.sql
RUN chmod -R 777 /etc/mysql/
RUN cp /etc/mysql/seed-data.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 3306
```

This has previously successfully spun up a container and was usable up until a few days ago.  I'm now getting some errors - Status: Exited(1) in Docker Desktop with all else being the same.  These are the logs:

```
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.1.0-1.el8 started.
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.1.0-1.el8 started.
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
[System] [MY-015017] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - start.
[Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
[System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.1.0) initializing of server in progress as process 80 mysqld: Error writing file '/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf' (OS errno 28 - No space left on device)
[ERROR] [MY-010076] [Server] Initialization of the server's UUID failed because it could not be read from the auto.cnf file. If this is a new server, the initialization failed because it was not possible to generate a new UUID.
[ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
[System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.1.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[System] [MY-015018] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - end.
```

As a sanity check, I remove the lines from the Dockerfile that are specific to my app, specifically copying the seed script

```
FROM mysql:latest

RUN chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/

ARG MYSQL_DATABASE
ARG MYSQL_USER
ARG MYSQL_PASSWORD
ARG MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQL_DATABASE
ENV MYSQL_USER=$MYSQL_USER
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

EXPOSE 3306
```

The container still fails to run with the below logs:

```
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.1.0-1.el8 started.
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.1.0-1.el8 started.
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
[MY-015017] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - start.
[MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
[MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.1.0) initializing of server in progress as process 80
[MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
[MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
[MY-010954] [Server] Performance schema tables initialization failed.
[MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
[MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
[MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.1.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[MY-015018] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - end.
```

Would this be indicative of an issue with the underlying image that I'm using?

Comment: `OS errno 28 - No space left on device` - did you check whether this is true? Also, it might be a good idea to tag the MySQL version you are using, unless you **really** want to use the most recent MySQL version

Comment: That is a great suggestion, thank you!  I've updated my Dockerfile to pin to `mysql:8.0`.  With respect to the space on device error message - the machine I'm running Docker Desktop on has 10's of GBs free, I've also cleaned up unused images, containers and volumes in Docker Desktop and got the same error.  I'm guessing this message is with respect to the volume that is attached to the container?  Does that sound right?